# Google Cloud Pub/Sub - Message delivery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-pubsub

Google Cloud Pub/Sub supports both exactly once (for pull subscriptions) and atleast once delivery guarantee. However there is no mention of associated cost if we opt for one of these mode in the doc - https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/pricing.

Question: is there any pricing difference when choosing these delivery modes in pub/sub?

Comment: No pricing difference, you pay per message and message size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly once and at-least-once delivery both cost the same: $40/TiB.